# how to change border into bubble cartoon

Tags: java, android, graphics, border, drawable

So i want to change the border of my layout to some kind of a bubble like in the comics / cartoons. I know i can change my border like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape     android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners  android:radius="5dip" />
            <stroke  android:width="2dip" android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

but how i can do the pointy part (the one which looks like a triangle). I need to use it to point what i tapped on.
I know it's sound odd or funny, but i need to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You can provide *Stroke Corner* but no complex curve(triangle), For custom shape you can use view and in onDraw()

```
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(160.0f, 240.0f);
path.lineTo(140.0f, 200.0f);
path.addArc(new RectF(140, 180, 180, 220), -180, 180);
path.lineTo(160.0f, 240.0f);
path.close();
```

This path will draw in canvas using,

**canvas.drawPath(path, paint);**

[image]

Better to create image with `9Patch` concept. [image]

This tool will help to build 9Patch image easily http://android.elex.pe.kr/a-better-9-patch-tool

Comment: So that means that the one on top and the one on the left are always stretchable and the one on the bottom and the right are always for the padding ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option would probably be to make a 9-patch image that looks like a speech bubble. This would allow the bubble to grow to the size of the text within it, without stretching or looking funny.

Otherwise it might be a bit complicated to draw it directly - you'd need to draw a triangle-like object at the bottom of the rectangle, either in XML or create a custom component and overwrite the painting methods - much more complicated.

9-patch images are used in many Android GUI components like Buttons and TeXtFields - basically you just need to create the 9-patch image and then set it as the background for the component. This can be done in the XML.

There are plenty of examples for creating 9-patch images, and the android SDK comes with a 9-patch tool that will create a 9-patch for any image you give it. See this link for the 9-patch tool... http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 0):

I made a [sample project](http://code.google.com/p/speechballoonsample/) that displays a ListView where all the items are displayed in speech balloons.  Feel free to download and use it.  By the way, that gray mud isn't an accident; it's the drop shadow from the original [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/OmniGraffle/) source art.  As the other writers suggested, it uses 9-patch drawables.
[image: Screen shot]

Comment: It looks good, but there is no download link, so i can test it.

Comment: You can sync the whole source tree here: http://code.google.com/p/speechballoonsample/source/checkout or you can save individual files starting here: http://code.google.com/p/speechballoonsample/source/browse/